# change the value in jsonresponse for particular user

Tags: flutter, api, dart

```json
{
    "User": {
        "id": "iERl6YK6mEmzpotHBvVBiA",
        "lastUpdated": 1643789241,
        "userInputWeightInKG": "70",
        "hasPhoto": true,
        "introDone": true,
        "photoTime": 1643621107,
        "photofmt": "png",
        "firstName": "new user",
        "lastName": "new user",
        "dateOfBirth": "01/31/1994",
        "email": "newuser123@gmail.com",
        "gender": "m",
        "heightMeters": 1.7,
        "fingerPrint": "",
        "aadhaarNumber": "",
        "mobileNumber": "2159863566",
        "higiScore": 200.0,
        "user_score": {
            "A1": 23,
            "A2": 8,
            "A3": 13,
            "A4": 28,
            "A5": 8,
            "A6": 28,
            "A7": 8,
            "A8": 23,
            "B1": 28,
            "B2": 28,
            "B3": 28,
            "B4": 28,
            "C1": 22,
            "C2": 8,
            "C3": 8,
            "C4": 8,
            "C5": 22,
            "D1": 19,
            "D2": 19,
            "D3": 19,
            "D4": 19,
            "E1": 0,
            "E2": 0,
            "E3": 0,
            "E4": 0,
            "T": 408
        },
        "accountCreated": "/Date(1643621096288+0530)/",
        "termsHistory": [
            {
                "termsAgreedDate": "/Date(1643621116912+0530)/",
                "termsFileName": "termsofuse_v9_01122016"
            }
        ],
        "terms": {
            "termsAgreedDate": "/Date(1643621116912+0530)/",
            "termsFileName": "termsofuse_v9_01122016"
        },
        "privacyAgreed": {
            "privacyAgreedDate": "/Date(1643621116912+0530)/",
            "privacyFileName": "privacypolicy_v7_08112014"
        },
        "privacyAgreedHistory": [
            {
                "privacyAgreedDate": "/Date(1643621116912+0530)/",
                "privacyFileName": "privacypolicy_v7_08112014"
            }
        ],
        "Notifications": {
            "EmailCheckins": "true",
            "EmailMonthlyRecap": "true",
            "EmailHigisphereNotifications": "true",
            "EmailHigiNews": "true",
            "EmailMonthlyDigest": "true"
        },
        "currentHigiScore": 0.0,
        "hasPassword": true,
        "privacy": {
            "leaderBoard": {
                "enabled": false
            },
            "thirdPartySharing": {
                "nonIdentifiableSharing": true
            }
        },
        "tags": {
            "isEarndItUser": false,
            "testTag1": 12345
        },
        "joint_user_detail_list": {
            "joint_user1": {
                "ihl_user_id": "17Jf3sYhwkGjNaAPPvZugQ",
                "ihl_user_name": "firstuser",
                "status": "requested",
                "vital_read": true,
                "vital_write": true,
                "teleconsult_read": true,
                "teleconsult_write": true
            },
            "joint_user2": {
                "ihl_user_id": "n9RFAVPnvEitJhESoTnFtg",
                "ihl_user_name": "seconduser",
                "status": "Active",
                "vital_read": true,
                "vital_write": true,
                "teleconsult_read": true,
                "teleconsult_write": true
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is my response from api..
i have to change the "joint_user2": status of guest user to from "Active" to "Inactive" if i click on that second user in UI
how can i do that
please help

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest creating a class which stores your user data. Then, using a fromMap() or fromJSON() method, you can create an object from your API response. You can have a look at the JSON Serialiser on pub.dev (https://pub.dev/packages/json_serializable).

After that, changing any of the values of that object becomes trivial.

```
onPressed: () {
    guestUser.status = 'Inactive' / UserStatus.Inactive ;
}
```

I would recommend using enums or some other set value type rather than a string, if you need to perform operations on the guest user's status.

Comment: thanks for your reply... i will try it out